# Petit Fat File system on AVR 8-bit, SPI Flash memory

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am using Petit Fat File system for my AVR - 8 bit MCU. I want to port it to flash memory. I am compiling the sources in host Linux PC and programming AVR.

I am getting an error of FR_NO_FILESYSTEM(6) for the function pf_mount().
It means 'There is no valid FAT partition on the drive'.
I should get FR_OK(0) for the success of the function pf_mount().

How do I fix this error.?